# Echo from another file into another files div

Tags: php

Hello im trying to upload a image it works perfectly however i want the user to know that the image actully have been uploaded, how can  i make this echo which is on upload.php appear in the echo div the form is into?

index.html

```
        <div id ="echo"><form action = "upload.php" id = "bildUppladdning"  method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" target = "hiddenFrame">
    <input type = "file" name = "file" id = "fileToUpload" accept="image/*" style = "display:none" onchange="form.submit()">
    </form></div>
```

upload.php

```
echo '<div id = "scs"> Your image was succesfully uploaded</div>';
```

Am i stupid or is this easier than i think? (brainlag) so i joined this site! Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's already in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php you just need to incorporate your div in it.

Comment: Faster than me mate! @Fred-ii-

Comment: @LelioFaieta php.net and I are "like this" (holding 2 fingers together) ;-)

Comment: Ahahah! Tipical Italian behavior! Thumbs up @Fred-ii-

Comment: @LelioFaieta *certo mi amico!*

Comment: wait how does that help me? the echo there is still in another file right? @Fred-ii-

Comment: without see the php for this, is anybody's guess really. Edit: @LelioFaieta you want a go at this? ;-)

Comment: Ahaha @Fred-ii- I'm on mobile, this is your turn amico mio!!!

Comment: @Fred-ii- it shouldn't be any need for more i just want this echo to be displayed at my index file when i upload an image instead of in the upload.php file, do  you understand? >.<

Comment: *"do you understand?"* - Yes, I understood *perfectly* and I told you what to do; RTM. If you want another method, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php - Added tip: `if/else` ;-)

Comment: @LelioFaieta Strangest thing; OP's profile seems to have been deleted and the question is still alive. I guess they were either a troll or just gave up.

Comment: *"so i joined this site"* - Funny how this guy knew how to ping someone, troll.